# Different definitions of cross-covariance matrix

Tags: matrices, covariance, correlation

In [wikipedia of covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-covariance_matrix) as well many textbooks on probability and statistics, the cross-covariance matrix $X$ and $Y$ is defined as
$$K_{XY} = E[(X - E[X])(Y - E[Y])]$$

However, in a lot of book in the field of electrical engineering (e.g., in "[Baseband Receiver Design for Wireless MIMO-OFDM Communications](https://www.google.nl/books/edition/Baseband_Receiver_Design_for_Wireless_MI/zfX0Ow6x2tkC?hl=zh-CN&gbpv=1&dq=Baseband%20Receiver%20Design%20for%20Wireless%20MIMO-OFDM%20Communications&printsec=frontcover)"), it seems that the cross-covariance matrix between $X$ and $Y$ is defined as
$$K_{XY} = E[XY^{H}],$$
where $(\cdot)^{H}$ is conjugate transpose operation. Also it seems that in the aforementioned book the terms "cross-correlation matrix" and "cross-covariance matrix" are used interchangably.

[image]

[image]

So is this difference of definition due to the specific field? Or the authors have misused the term in the books?

Comment: it's the same up to a constant, so it doesn't really matter